# Custom ConstraintValidator called twice

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.2.RELEASE version which includes 'hibernate-validator' 5.3.4.Final version.

I'm facing an issue which my implementation class for ConstraintValidator executed twice.

I have attached here source code.

1. Interface

> @RestController @Validated @FunctionalInterface public interface
>   IBinRegistryApi {
>
> ```
> /**
>  *
>  * @param lookupRequest
>  * @param nonce
>  * @return
>  */
> @PostMapping(value = "/xxx/yyy/zzz/XYZ", headers="Accept=application/json",
>         produces= {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
>         consumes= {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
> ResponseEntity getWalletByCard(NonceValid @RequestHeader(value = "X-Captcha-Nonce") String nonce); }
> ```

2. Implementation

> @Component @Validated @Slf4j public class BinRegistryApiImpl
>   implements IBinRegistryApi {
>       @Override
>       public ResponseEntity getWalletByCard(NonceValid @RequestHeader(value = "X-Captcha-Nonce") String nonce) { }

3. NonceValid interface

> @Target({ElementType.PARAMETER}) @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
>   @Documented @Constraint(validatedBy=NonceValidator.class) public
>   @interface NonceValid {
>       String message() default "Nonce is invalid";
>
> ```
> Class<?>[] groups() default {};
>
> Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {}; }
> ```

4. NonceValidator class

> public class NonceValidator implements ConstraintValidator {
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void initialize(NonceValid constraintAnnotation) {
>     // no initialization required
> }
>
> @Override
> public boolean isValid(String nonce, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
>       **// twice here**
> } }
> ```

Anyone experience the same issue?

**Note 1**: I do see the my Custom Validator is belong to 2 groups which is IBinRegistryAPI and **Default**. That is why it is executed twice I believe

**Note 2**: If I change the implementation to Validator and Custom Group, the issue is not happening.

Thanks,

Comment: It's great. Thanks a lot.